# onclick event for radio button using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, onclick, radio-button

How do I implement “onclick” event using JavaScript for radio button controls in a C# class to change a hidden Server Control Textbox Text value to reflect which button is clicked?   The buttons are html controls running on the client.

Say I have 2 radio buttons: Button1 and Button2.  In my C# code, I need to replace the alert calls below to update my Textbox control, the value in this hidden will be processed on PostBack.

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(' You clicked Button 1. How do I update textBox.Text? in here?');");       
Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('You clicked Button 2. How do I update textBox.Text? in here?');");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
document.getElementById('myTextbox').value = 'Button1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your hidden text box runs at the server side, it's Id is unknown. You need to obtain the client id.

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('" + Textbox1.ClientId + "').value = this.ID");

Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('" + Textbox1.ClientId + "').value = this.ID");
```

Remember you need to hide the text box with JavaScript or use a hiddenInput control instead.

Comment: Using `javascript:` in an onclick won't work, and at the end, it's probably `this.id` but I know that's just an example

Answer (score 1):

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "').value = 'Button1'");

      Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "').value = 'Button2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something interesting. While you can create these radio buttons dynamically, it doesn't look like you can automatically connect them to a code-behind handler. However, you can add a button to the page, give it a code-behind handler, and then use a JavaScript onClick handler to click that button. From there, you can look at the radio buttons and do something.

For example:

```
protected void MyFunction
{
...
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
radioButton.Text = "Text";
radioButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", @"obj=document.getElementById('MainContent_ButtonGroupRadioButtonsClicked');obj.click();");
radioButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
...
}
```

protected void OnRadioButtonGroupClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  // Do something here.
}